# How can I ensure I have the same versions of dependencies in build and test using Ivy?

Tags: dependencies, ivy

I have a project with 2 configurations, test and runtime. test extends runtime as I assume I need all runtime dependencies to run the tests.

How can I ensure that the extra dependencies in the test conf don't pull in later versions of something in runtime. For example if my project expresses a runtime dependency on commons-collections 2.1.1 and a test-time dependency on htmlunit 2.9 (which has its own dependency on commons-collections 3.2.1). How do I ensure I don't test using commons-collections 3.2.1 and then deploy using commons-collections 2.1.1?

Edit: If possible, I would like a solution which doesn't rely on knowing which modules are being affected. That would mean that I don't have to check for this every time I change any dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use [exclude on the dependency](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.1.0/ivyfile/artifact-exclude.html), to make sure the transitive dependency you specify is ignored. This is different than [a module exclude](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.1.0/ivyfile/exclude.html), which will exclude the dependency across the entire project.

Comment: cheers, This sounds like a good solution once I have spotted a particular issue but I was hoping for a more general solution where I won't have to check for this every time I change the dependencies.